# Does the Riemann-Stieltjes integrability of $f^3$ imply the Riemann-Stieltjes integrability of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function defined on the open interval $(a,b)$. Does the Riemann-Stieltjes integrability of $f^3$ imply the Riemann-Stieltjes integrability of $f$ ?

## My attempt :  I thinks yes

If $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable, and $\varphi : (c,d)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous where $f((a,b))\subset (c,d)$, then $\varphi\circ f$ is Riemann integrable.

Is its true ?

Comment: Is $f$ allowed to be complex? If not, then $f$ can be defined to be discontinuous everywhere while $f^3\equiv 1$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts if $f$ allowed  complex  then what  type of function  u will take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by DisintegratingByParts, this is indeed not true in the case where $f$ is real-valued. An explicit counterexample $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\
1,&\text{ if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

I'll leave you to check that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, but $f^n \equiv 0$ for all $n \geq 2$.

**EDIT**: I here assumed that OP meant $f^3$ by $f \circ f \circ f$, and not by $x \mapsto (f(x))^3$. If OP meant the latter, then the statement becomes true as the map $x \mapsto x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Perhaps I’m mistaken but isn’t $f^n = f$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in your example?

Comment: Clement, I think by $f^3$ the OP means the cube of $f$, not $f\circ f\circ f$.

Comment: @TonyK I assumed that's what jasmine meant since they included the theorem on composition preserves Riemann integrability. I'll make an edit on my post.

Comment: @ClementYung  im talking in $ f : (a, b)   \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ why u r taking $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ??

Comment: @jasmine you're right, but you can construct a very similar function and yield the same results. The idea is that the domain might have both rational and irrational numbers, but you can force the image to only have rational numbers.

Comment: okkss @Clement Yung thanks u